# Dynamicaly creating and removing a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dynamic

I have been strugling with this for a while and I am sure there is a simple answer to this. What happens is I remove a div called "payment" then dynamicaly create it again so I can add to it. That then gets repeated as the infomation that needs to be added to it changes.

I have mangaged to get this so far.

```
function clearPage()
{
    var d = document.getElementById("contain"); 
    var d_nested = document.getElementById("payment"); 
    var deleteNode = d.removeChild(d_nested);

}

function createPayment()
{
    payment = document.createElement("div");
    payment.id = "mine";
    document.getElementById("contain").appendChild(payment);
}

function printOnPage()
{
    var x = names.length;
    for( var i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
    {
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var paymentDiv = document.getElementById("payment");
        paymentDiv.appendChild(para);
        var txtName = document.createTextNode("Item: ");
        para.appendChild(txtName);
        var txtNameArray = document.createTextNode(names[i]);
        para.appendChild(txtNameArray);
        var txtQty = document.createTextNode(" Qty: ");
        para.appendChild(txtQty);
        var txtQtyArray = document.createTextNode(qty[i]);
        para.appendChild(txtQtyArray);
        var txtCost = document.createTextNode(" Cost: ");
        para.appendChild(txtCost);
        var txtCostArray = document.createTextNode(prices[i]);
        para.appendChild(txtCostArray);
    }
}
```

Related HTML

```
<div id="contain">
    <p>Payment</p>
        <div id="payment">  
            <br />
        </div>
</div>
```

It needs the ID of payment for both my CSS rules and for my creating the text that goes in it.

This is the error I get in FireFox

> Error: paymentDiv is null Source File:
>   http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/ks339/sem2/javascript/js.js Line: 76

Hope someone can provide some insight in to this and please tell me if I am completly off!

Thanks

Edit: Is it easior to clear the div rather than delete it, how would I go about doing such a thing?

Comment: why are you completely removing the `div`? why not just clear it and then stuff it?

Comment: @Eonasdan I was unaware you where able to do this? How would you go about doing this?

Comment: how are you calling your functions? what is the order? i think you're deleting the div before getting it's id.

Comment: @Th0rndike This is the current order ` clearPage();
 createPayment();
 printOnPage(); `

Comment: Then the problem is what Nate said

Comment: you can clear the contents by simply doing `$("#payment").html("")`. this may not actually be what you need. Maybe __you__ need to do it that way. just a suggestion.

Comment: oops! I also assumed you were using jquery. If that's not the case then I can't recall how to do that in POJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In create_payment(), you set the ID to 'mine'. Shouldn't it be 'payment'?

Comment: -_- Thank you so much, I knew it was somthing obvious like that. + answer and selected as best (When I can)

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your requirements very well, but anyway you cannot create multiple items in the page using the same id attribute, if you want to duplicate an item and still have control over it, you should be using class instead.

Try switching your code into jquery it will be cleaner and easier to understand for you & me.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's rather hard to explain. However, I have no sorted the issue out thanks to Nate. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the fact that in createPayment() you're setting the id to 'mine':

`payment.id = "mine";`

while later on in printOnPage() you're looking for the element using id 'payment':

`var paymentDiv = document.getElementById("payment");`

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in your edit, it is far easier just to clear the div than to remove it, specially if you still need it later.

To clear a DIV-block just set it's content to *empty*:

```
document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "";
```

I hope you find a solution! Good luck!